# Displaying nodes count in slurm output filename

Tags: count, nodes, filenames, slurm

Is it possible to format SLURM filename(using --output) with requested nodes count(-N)? e.g if submit a slurm script like "sbatch -N 4  --output=out-%j.txt abc.script", can the output filename have 4 in it? Currently, this shows jobid only.

Answer (score 1):

`sbatch` does not offer that possibility. There two options:

1. use an environment variable during submission to hold the number of nodes:

   NNODES=4 sbatch -N $NNODES --output=out-%j.$NNODES.txt abc.script

Note that this will not work if you insert the `--output` option in the submission script, only in the command line.

2. ignore the `--output`  option and redirect the output of your program explicitly. In your `abs.script` have something like:

   srun ./myprogram.exe > out-$SLURM_JOBID.$SLURM_JOB_NUM_NODES.txt

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I was wondering why SLURM doesn't has this option.